# API's URL is not working in loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am accessing data through API of some website. i am using it in a loop in order to get 114 JSON responses, one by one. but it is not working and showing error :
**code**

```
        for (var counter = 1; counter < 114; counter++) {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true, jsonpCallback: 'quranData' }); // define ajax setup
            $.getJSON("http://api.globalquran.com/surah/"+counter+"/quran-simple?jsoncallback=?", {
                format: "jsonp"
            }, function (Obj) {
                $.each(Obj.quran, function (i, by) {
                    $.each(by, function (verseNo, line) {
                        var obj = {
                            'ayah_no': line.ayah_no,
                            'ayah': line.ayah,
                            'surah': line.surah,
                            'verse': line.verse
                        };
                        c++;
                        num++;
                        things.push(obj);
                     });
                 });
return false;
              });
        }
```

but it is showing error on browser console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'quranData' of object [object Object] is not a function quran-simple?jsoncallback=quranData&format=jsonp:1
```

what to do to run this loop ?

Answer (score 0):

do you define the function **quranData**?

you must set only once the $.ajaxSetup (before your loop for example)

Answer (score 0):

try to get entire Quran in one call. it saves at least 10 seconds of calling. 
http://api.globalquran.com/complete/quran-simple?format=json
then parse using json data.

hope it helps